# Gone ortho-flogging

Tags: no-computers, mazes

Well played,
[Scratchy](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-scratch-golfer-1560979),
you just took 8 shots on Hole 9 of
Puzzlington Municipal Ortho-flog Course!

```
         As presented                         As flogged (solved) by you
 -----------------------------           ------------------------------------

                      Cup                 <pre>
                    (begin)                        7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
                       |                           6               1
                                                   5           4 3 2 1 2
                                                   4           1   3   1
   Hole 9        . . .(0)                          3           2   4 . 1(0)
                 .     .                           2           3   5     .
   3 left        .     .                           1           4   6     .
   5 down        .     .                           6 5 4 3 2 1 5   7     .
                 .     .                                           8     .
                [ ]. . o o                                        [9]. . o o
                                          </pre>

                 |      |                 SCORE = 8 shots
                Tee   Trees
               (end) (avoid)         (periods . are grid marks for reference)
```

What the “ortho-flog”?
 
Just **backwards** “**golf**,” of course,
on an orthogonal grid. 
At each hole**:**

- Begin at the `(0)` cup, end at the `[ ]` tee.
- Make a path of consecutive “shots.” 
  The path may overlap itself but not `o` trees.
- The *more* shots the better. 
  For equal shot counts, longer shots are favored.
- Shots alternate between up-or-down (1 step = 1 line)
  and left-or-right (1 step = **2** character spaces),
  starting in any of those directions.
- Each successive shot is **longer** than the last,
  but never longer than 9. 
  (In the order flogged above, shots at Hole 9 are
  1 left, 2 up, 4 left,       5 down,
  6 left, 7 up, 8 right, 9 down.)
- Surround your solution with `<pre>` and `</pre>`
  to produce even typewriter-like spacing.

Try for the greatest total shot count over all 9 holes. 
Please use [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers), though,
as this course is not meant to accommodate byte supremacism. 
Here is your scorecard so far.

```
     ________________________________________________________________________
    |          |       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
    |   SCORE  |   8   |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |  8  |
    |          |_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
    |          |       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |1 2  |
    |   Shot   |       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |4 5 6|
    |  lengths |   42  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |7 8 9|
    |          |_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
    |            Total    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9  |
    |                                                                        |
    |If total scores are equal, the largest total of shot lengths is favored.|
    | If length totals are also equal, square each shot length and re-total. |
    |   Repeat with cubes and so on as long as those totals remain equal.    |
    |________________________________________________________________________|
```

[**E R O F !**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore_(golf))

```
                                                                            .
    Hole 8                          . . . . .(0)                            .
                                    .         .                             .
    5 left                        o .         .                             .
    4 down                          .         .                             .
                                   [ ]        .                             .
                                    . . . . . .                             .
                                          o                                 .
```

```
                                                                            .
    Hole 7                            . . . .(0)                            .
                                      .       .                             .
    5 left                            . o     .                             .
    4 down                            .       .                             .
                                   [ ].       .                             .
                                      . . . . .                             .
                                              o                             .
```

```
                                            o                               .
    Hole 6                            . . . . .                             .
                                      .      (0)                            .
    5 left                            .       .                             .
    4 down                            .       .                             .
                                      .       .                             .
                                   [ ].       .                             .
                                      . . . . .                             .
                                          o                                 .
```

```
                          . . . . . o . o . o . o . . . .                   .
    Hole 5                .     o                   o   .                   .
                          .                           o .                   .
    9 left                . o   . . . . o . o . . .     .                   .
    8 down                .     .   o           o .     o                   .
                          o     . o               .     .                   .
                          .     .     . o o .     o     o                   .
                          o     o     .    (0)    .     .                   .
                          .     .     o     . o o .     o                   .
                          o     o     .                 .                   .
                          .     .     o               o .                   .
                          o     o     . . o . o . o . . .                   .
                          .     .                                           .
                          o     . o                                         .
                          .     . . . o . o . o . o . o . o . o             .
                         [ ]                                                .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                                                            .
    Hole 4              . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .(0)            .
                        .                                     .             .
   19 left              .                                     .             .
    7 down              .                                     .             .
                        .                                     .             .
                        .                                     .             .
                        .                                     .             .
                       [ ]. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                                  o                         .
    Hole 3                        . . . . . . . .(0)                        .
                                  .               .                         .
    8 left                        .               .                         .
    5 down                        .               .                         .
                                  .               .                         .
                                 [ ]. . . . . . . .                         .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                              o                             .
    Hole 2                        . . . . . . . . .                         .
                                  .              (0)                        .
    8 left                        .               . o                       .
    3 down                        .               .                         .
                                 [ ]. . . . . . . .                         .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                                  o                         .
    Hole 1                        o o . . . . . . .                         .
                                    .             .                         .
    1 down                          .  (0)        .                         .
                                    .  [ ]  o o   .                         .
                                  o . . . . . . . .                         .
                                    o                                       .
```

Any solution should begin with a summary scorecard, copied from above.
As always, some analysis is expected.

Comment: Can I get a hole in one?

Comment: A _**tee** in one_  is only possible on Hole 1, though it would be the worst possible score

Comment: Can we have multiple shots of length 9, or does a shot of length 9 *have* to be the shot that gets it to the tee?

Comment: I'm feeling very dim. What is the significance of the dots? I'd have assumed they indicate a path you're supposed to be restricted to, but the "Hole 9" example has the ball taking a route that seems to take no notice of the dots. I suspect I'm missing something that's obvious to everyone other than me...

Comment: (Perhaps they're just there to make it more visually apparent what the relative positions of cup and tee and trees are, and e.g. a regular grid of dots would have done just as well?)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Underneath the solved hole: "(periods . are grid marks for reference)"

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that.

Comment: At most one shot of length 9, and none is okay too, @DqwertyC, the puzzle statement has been revised. Thank you for pointing out an ambiguity.

Comment: Dots `.` near `[ ]` and `(0)` are there just to help measure spacing. Dots along the right margin ensure the presence of spaces to facilitate the editing of rightward shots. (Entirely filling the grid with dots made things surprisingly more difficult to see.)

Comment: When your path crosses itself, does it have to be on the same number?

Comment: Doesn't have to be the same number on crossings, @boboquack, sorry about the false artifact.

Comment: Do I have to stop when I reach the tee? Or can I keep on playing? Very original and amusingly presented puzzle, by the way.

Comment: Dear @Laska, you may keep playing to your heart's delight. That's how I play miniature golf. This puzzle, though, is meant to stop at the tee. Ain't that backwards enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Warning: I have answers for everything, without spoilers blocks

After much pen-and-paper case bashing (like, 10 pages worth - I am *not* going to reproduce it here) this is what I came up with:

> ```
>      ________________________________________________________________________
>     |          |       |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
>     |   SCORE  |  60   |  1  |  5  |  8  |  8  |  2  |  8  |  9  |  9  |  8  |
>     |          |_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
>     |          |       |1    |1   3|1 2 3|1 2  |     |1   3|1 2 3|1 2 3|1 2  |
>     |   Shot   |       |     |4 5  |4 5 6|4 5 6|     |4 5 6|4 5 6|4 5 6|4 5 6|
>     |  lengths |   ??  |     |  8  |7   9|7 8 9|  8 9|7 8 9|7 8 9|7 8 9|7 8 9|
>     |          |_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
>     |            Total    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9  |
>     |                                                                        |
>     |If total scores are equal, the largest total of shot lengths is favored.|
>     | If length totals are also equal, square each shot length and re-total. |
>     |   Repeat with cubes and so on as long as those totals remain equal.    |
>     |________________________________________________________________________|
> ```

```
                                         6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                     .
                                         5             1                     .
                                         4   2 1 2 3   2                     .
                                         3   1     1   3                     .
     Hole 8                          . . 2 . 1(0)  2   4                     .
                                     .   1     .   3   5                     .
     5 left                        o .   5 4 3 2 1 4   6                     .
     4 down                          .         .       7                     .
                                    [9]8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8                     .
                                     . . . . . .                             .
                                           o                                 .
```

```
                                                                            .
    Hole 7                            . . . .(0)1                           .
                                      .       . 1                           .
    5 left                            . o 3 2 1 2                           .
    4 down                            .   1   .                             .
                  8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8[9].   2   .                             .
                  7                   . . 3 . .                             .
                  6             5 4 3 2 1 4   o                             .
                  5             1                                           .
                  4             2                                           .
                  3             3                                           .
                  2             4                                           .
                  1             5                                           .
                  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 6                                           .
```

```
                                    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7                       .
                                    1               6                       .
                                    2   4 3 2 1 3   5                       .
                                    3   1   o   2   4                       .
    Hole 6                          4 . 2 . . . 1   3                       .
                                    5 . 3    (0)1   2                       .
    5 left                          6 . 4     .     1                       .
    4 down                          7 . 5 1 2 3 4 5 6                       .
                                    8 .       .                             .
                                   [9].       .                             .
                                      . . . . .                             .
                                          o                                 .
```

```
                          . . . . . o . o . o . o . . . .                   .
    Hole 5                .     o                   o   .                   .
                          .                           o .                   .
    9 left                . o   . . . . o . o . . .     .                   .
    8 down                .     .   o           o .     o                   .
                          o     . o               .     .                   .
                          .     .     . o o .     o     o                   .
                          o     o     .    (0)    .     .                   .
                          .     .     o     1 o o .     o                   .
                          o     o     .     2           .                   .
                          .     .     o     3         o .                   .
                          o     o     . . o 4 o . o . . .                   .
                          .     .           5                               .
                          o     . o         6                               .
                          .     . . . o . o 7 o . o . o . o . o             .
                         [9]8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8                               .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                                                            .
                                          7 6 5 4 3 2 1 6                   .
    Hole 4              . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 5 . .(0)            .
                        .                 2             4     1 1 2         .
   19 left              .                 3             3     .   1         .
    7 down              .                 4             2     .   2         .
                        .                 5             1     .   3         .
                        .                 6             5 4 3 2 1 4         .
                        .                 7                   .             .
                       [9]8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 . . . . . . . . . .             .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 6                           .
                                  1             5                           .
                                  2             4   2 1 2 3                 .
                                  3             3 o 1     1                 .
    Hole 3                        4 . . . . . . 2(0)1     2                 .
                                  5             1 .       3                 .
    8 left                        6             5 4 3 2 1 4                 .
    5 down                        7               .                         .
                                  8               .                         .
                                 [9]. . . . . . . .                         .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                  5 4 3 2 1 4                               .
                                  1         3                               .
                                  2         2                               .
                                  3         1 o                             .
    Hole 2                        4 . . . . 3 2 1 1                         .
                                  5              (0)                        .
    8 left                        6               . o                       .
    3 down                        7               .                         .
                                 [8]. . . . . . . .                         .
                                                                            .
```

```
                                                  o                         .
    Hole 1                        o o . . . . . . .                         .
                                    .             .                         .
    1 down                          .  (0)        .                         .
                                    .  [1]  o o   .                         .
                                  o . . . . . . . .                         .
                                    o                                       .
```

I believe I have proved uniqueness for most of the holes, but am not sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

### Hole 8, Score 9

> ```
>                                          6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                      .
>                                          5             1                     .
>                                          4   2 1 2 3   2                     .
>                                          3   1     1   3                     .
>      Hole 8                          . . 2 . 1(0)  2   4                     .
>                                      .   1     .   3   5                     .
>      5 left                        o .   5 4 3 2 1 4   6                     .
>      4 down                          .         .       7                     .
>                                     [9]8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8                     .
>                                      . . . . . .                             .
>                                            o                                 .
> ```
>
> ```
> LEFT | +1  -3  +5  -7  +9 | +5
> DOWN |   -2  +4  -6  +8   | +4
> ```

I think this is the only possible answer for hole 8 with score 9.

Hole 7 and hole 6 are also 5 steps left and 4 steps down, but the same route is blocked by a tree. So some numbers should be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

## Partial answer - Holes 7, 6 and 3

### Hole 7 - score 9

> ```
>                                                                             .
>     Hole 7                            . . . .(0)1                           .
>                                       .       . 1                           .
>     5 left                            . o 3 2 1 2                           .
>     4 down                            .   1   .                             .
>                   8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8[9].   2   .                             .
>                   7                   . . 3 . .                             .
>                   6             5 4 3 2 1 4   o                             .
>                   5             1
>                   4             2
>                   3             3
>                   2             4
>                   1             5
>                   7 6 5 4 3 2 1 6
> ```

### Hole 6 - score 8

> ```
>                                     8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7
>                                     1               6
>                                     2   4 3 2 1 3   5
>                                     3   1   o   2   4                       .
>     Hole 6                          4 . 2 . . . 1   3                       .
>                                     5 . 3    (0)1   2                       .
>     5 left                          6 . 4     .     1                       .
>     4 down                          7 . 5 1 2 3 4 5 6                       .
>                                     8 .       .                             .
>                                    [9].       .                             .
>                                       . . . . .                             .
>                                           o                                 .
> ```

### Hole 3 - score 7

> ```
>                                       6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>                                       5             1
>                                       4           o 2                       .
>     Hole 3                        . . 3 . . . 2 1(0)3                       .
>                                   .   2       1   . 4                       .
>     8 left                        .   1       2   . 5                       .
>     5 down                        .   4 3 2 1 3   . 6                       .
>                                   .               . 7                       .
>                                  [9]8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8                       .
>                                                                             .
> ```

NB: I believe these are optimal but I might have missed something.